# columns ignore height of it's parent

Tags: html, height, parent

The problem is that the parent `div` should respect the text `height` of both columns (`#col1` and `#col2`, each using `float:left`). However, parent's height property (`#content`) acts like no text is written inside.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/Arkl1te/UWNaT/

I could insert a fixed height, but it shouldn't work like that: height should have a "flexible" value, even with text.

Comment: Here's the result using `overflow:hidden` inside `#content`: http://jsfiddle.net/Arkl1te/UWNaT/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the children are floating you have 2 options:

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the parent to respect the height of the children:

```
#content{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Add an empty element with `clear:both` as the latest element:

```
<div id="content">
 <p id="col1">...</p>
 <p id="col2">...</p>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `overflow: hidden` is fair enough! I rather edit the CSS than the html structure. Thanks man! :)